# How to represent CSS in SCSS

Tags: css

I've got the following css. I wanted this to convert to SCSS.

**CSS**

```
.thumbnail > img, .thumbnail a > img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Is it correct the way I've written it in SCSS?

```
.thumbnail{
  img{

  }
  a{
    img{

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

You've replaced all the child combinators with descendant selectors and discarded all of the rules.

Your original CSS will work just fine as SCSS:

```
.thumbnail > img, .thumbnail a > img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

You could make it marginally shorter by pulling out the class selector:

```
.thumbnail {
    &> img,
    a > img {
        display: block;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as the code in your question is concerned, you just forgot your child combinators (`>`)

```
.thumbnail {
  > img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  a {
    > img {
      display: block;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
  }
}
```

However, it could be a lot shorter, see Quentin's answer.

Comment: We are duplicating the code aren't we? could this be simplified like CSS? without have duplicate styles?

Comment: "direct-sibling" — They are **children** not "direct-siblings". There is no such thing as a "direct-sibling" in CSS.

Comment: Re edit: "direct-child" — They are children. The word "direct" has no meaning here. What is an indirect child? One that is adopted? On the web that would be an element that is moved with JS DOM manipulation and the child combinator would apply to that element.

Comment: This code is not optimised anyway - See Quentin's answer, for how it should be done without duplicating the styles

Comment: @AlonEitan True. I was a little too fast on answering and didn't quite think through

Comment: NP, your answer is still correct, just not optimised

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this:

```
.thumbnail {
  > img, a > img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}
```

Try using online converters.